# PHP - Laravel returning string instead of array (JSON)

Tags: php, laravel

I have a model called `CroppedDocumentField`, that have below `$casts` setup:

```
protected $casts = [
    'content' => 'array'
];
```

The migration looks like this:

```
Schema::create('cropped_document_fields', function(Blueprint $table){
      $table->increments('id');
      $table->unsignedInteger('document_id');
      $table->json('content')->nullable();
});
```

In my database, the content column seems to be stored like a string:

```
"{\"1\": [{\"row\": \"Bill Tc\\n\"}, {\"row\": \"Nathar\\n\"}, {\"row\": \"75839\\n\"}]}"
```

If I echo that out:

```
$document = CroppedDocumentField::Find(56);
dd(is_array($document->content));
```

This returns false.

When I insert the JSON to my database, I read it from a .txt file, that contains the JSON string:

```
{"1": [{"row": "Bill Tc\n"}, {"row": "Nathar\n"}, {"row": "75839\n"}]}
```

Then I insert it:

```
$file = "mytext.txt";
$content = file_get_contents($file);

//Add the text content
$this->document->cropped()->create([
     'content' => $content
]);
```

In my document model, I simply have a relationship to the `CroppedDocumentField` model:

```
//Document.php:
public function cropped()
{
    return $this->hasMany(CroppedDocumentField::class);
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @Tarasovych ah, fixed - it was a typo

Comment: What is the data type of the MySQL column? Is it VARCHAR?

Comment: The data type is `JSON` - will update my question to include the migration.

Comment: I believe the problem is because `file_get_contents` returns String, so that's why the data is stored like that. I have `json` column on my project, casting it to array is straight forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried casting json to array on my project and it worked as expected, what I believe the problem is the way you store the content. Please try changing it to this and let me know:

```
//Add the text content
$this->document->cropped()->create([
     'content' => json_decode($content) // convert string to json
]);
```

Comment: Ah, perfect! This converts the string to a valid JSON object. Thanks!